# What is the difference between this two await calls

Tags: c#, .net, async-await

I have the following code:

```
async Task Main()
{
    Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

    // Variante 1
    sw.Start();
    var m1 = await Task1();
    var m2 = await Task2();
    var m3 = await Task3();
    Console.WriteLine(m1);
    Console.WriteLine(m2);
    Console.WriteLine(m3);
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);

    // Variante 2
    sw.Restart();
    var t1 = Task1();
    var t2 = Task2();
    var t3 = Task3();
    m1 = await t1;
    m2 = await t2;
    m3 = await t3;
    Console.WriteLine(m1);
    Console.WriteLine(m2);
    Console.WriteLine(m3);
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
}

// Define other methods, classes and namespaces here
public async Task<string> Task1()
{
    await Task.Delay(5000);
    return "Task1 ready";
}   

public async Task<string> Task2()
{
    await Task.Delay(5000);
    return "Task2 ready";
}

public async Task<string> Task3()
{
    await Task.Delay(5000);
    return "Task3 ready";
}
```

The first part results in nearly 15000ms and the second one in 5000ms, but I don't get the point why!

In the first part I await an async method returning a Task and in the second part I get this Task and await the Task.

What am I missing?

Comment: In the first code block you start each task and wait for it to complete before moving to the next task and doing the same, they run in sequence where the next one only starts after the previous one completes. Think of that block like a relay race. In the second block of code you start each task first and then await them to completion one by one. They are running in parallel. Think of that like a race where everyone starts at the same time.

Comment: As an aside for future reference you can also wait for multiple things to finish using the `Task.WaitAll` method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The other answers are partially right, but I wanted to write my own answer to clear something up.

**The tasks are not started in parallel.**

Strictly speaking, "parallel" means that two lines of code are being evaluated simultaneously. That doesn't happen here.

Every asynchronous method starts out running synchronously. The magic happens when `await` acts on an incomplete `Task` (e.g. when an I/O request is started). At that point, the method *returns* its own incomplete `Task` and the continuation of the method is scheduled for later.

When you do this:

```
var t1 = Task1();
var t2 = Task2();
var t3 = Task3();
```

This is what happens:

1. `Task1` starts executing.
2. At the first `await`, `Task1` returns a `Task`.
3. `Task2` starts executing.
4. At the first `await`, `Task2` returns a `Task`.
5. `Task3` starts executing.
6. At the first `await`, `Task3` returns a `Task`.

So what makes this run faster is that your code uses the time while `Task1` is waiting for a response to start the request in `Task2`.

---

The *continuations* of those tasks *might* run in parallel depending on the circumstances.

In a situation where there is a synchronization context (like ASP.NET), the continuations must come back to the same context and nothing will run in parallel. That means that execution of `Task1` will not continue until the nothing else is running under that context. In your code, that happens at:

```
m1 = await t1;
```

Only after that line, the current context is freed, the continuation of `Task1` can run in that context, and when that's done, everything after `await t1` is put on the "to-do" list to complete.

If you are running in a situation where there is no synchronization context (like [ASP.NET Core](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2017/03/aspnetcore-synchronization-context.html)), or you specify `.ConfigureAwait(false)` to tell it that you do not need it to return to the same context, the continuations of the tasks will run on ThreadPool threads. That means that the continuations of all three tasks could run in parallel on different threads. If that happens, then by the time you hit `await t1`, it could already be done.

---

If you do this:

```
var m1 = await Task1();
var m2 = await Task2();
var m3 = await Task3();
```

You wait until `Task1` finishes entirely before even starting `Task2`. There is still benefit in this depending on your application. In ASP.NET, for example, it frees the thread to be used by some other unrelated request coming in. In a desktop app, it could free the UI thread to respond to user input.

Answer (score 5):

In variant 2, all three tasks have started before you call `await` on them. In variant 1, you wait for each to finish before starting the next.

Answer (score 1):

A `Task` starts running as soon as you call the method. You are calling `Task1`, `Task2`, and `Task3` without awaiting any of them, so they all start running simultaneously.

In the second part, you are calling `Task1`, then awaiting it, before calling `Task2` and `Task3`. This means `Task2` doesn't start until `Task1` finishes, and `Task3` doesn't start until `Task2` finishes. They run one after the other, stretching out the total run time.

Answer (score 1):

In the first code block you start each task and wait for it to complete before moving to the next task and doing the same, they run in sequence where the next one only starts after the previous one completes. Think of this like a relay race, each racer must wait for the previous racer to complete before starting.

In the second block of code you start each of the 3 tasks first and then await them to completion one by one. They are running in parallel because you started them at nearly the same time. Think of that like a race where everyone starts at the same time and then you wait for them to complete.

Answer (score -1):

The problem here is that you're including JIT compilation in your measures.

Have you tried switching the first option with the second to see how it measures?

If you look at [the compiler generated code](https://sharplab.io/#v2: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), you'll see that there are no significant differences.

The effectively measure performance, you need to use something like [BenchMarkDotNet](https://benchmarkdotnet.org/).